# Passing a method as a parameter with parameters

Tags: c#

So I know how to do:

```
void PrintFoo () { Console.Write("Foo");}
void DoSomething (Action methodToCall) { methodToCall();}
void Main () { DoSomething(PrintFoo);   }
```

What I want to do:

```
void PrintFoo (string fooToPrint) { Console.Write(fooToPrint);}
void DoSomething (Action methodToCall) { methodToCall();}
void Main () { DoSomething(PrintFoo("Foo bar baz"));   }
```

Basically call an action WITH Parameters

Answer (score 4):

Use a lambda expression:

```
void PrintSomething(string stringToPrint) { Console.Write(stringToPrint); }
void DoSomething(Action methodToCall) { methodToCall(); }

void Main() 
{ 
    DoSomething(() => PrintSomething("Message")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also define actions to require parameter types for the callback.

```
public void DoSomething(Action<string> Callback){
   var result = getMyString();
   Callback(result); 
}

public void DoSomething(Action<string> CallBack, List<string> Parms){
    var sb = new StringBuilder();        
    Parms.ForEach(p=> sb.Append(Parse(p));
    Callback(sb.ToString());
}
```